# SharePoint form link displays differently if clicked versus if copy-pasted into browser

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I created a form in SP designer then sent the link to some colleagues. Most clicked on the link in the email and were taken to a spotless and clean form. Another copy-pasted the link into their browser and got a form with auto-populated data. I noticed that the entire link shows different values. For this image, it had the following
trailing info: 
`Item/displayifs.aspx?List=8d8168e0%2De49a%2D418a%2D8f4b%2D206c64e946d7&ID=%5B%25Current%20Item%3AID%25%5D&Web=b5fdfbc0%2Dd5c5%2D4782%2D9b85%2D741134a544ba`

[image: er image description here]

versus this one which autopopulated the info: 
`Item/displayifs.aspx?List=8d8168e0%2De49a%2D418a%2D8f4b%2D206c64e946d7&ID=8&Web=b5fdfbc0%2Dd5c5%2D4782%2D9b85%2D741134a544ba`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) with their real characters, you will see that the difference is in the ID.

The first link has this value for the ID parameter: `[%Current Item:ID%]`, the second link has the value `8` as the ID parameter.

It's hard to tell WHY this happens without seeing the link that people actually have in their email.